# Allylic bromination with NBS

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

I know that NBS is a selective brominating agent especially on the **allylic position**. And its reaction mechanism is of free radical.

But I can't figure out the reason for the change in position of the double bond in the products.

It would be helpful if someone could give the mechanism along with its reason.

[image]

This is what I'm thinking, that might be happening there but still I don't understand how and why something like this would happen.

[image: for A]
[image: for B]

My mistake, number 3 and the product which I have marked as not formed are same.

2)**Which one among these three products (disregarding stereochemistry) is the *major product*?**

[image]

Comment: You're going through an allylic radical intermediate, right? How is the allylic radical stabilised?

Comment: The stabilization process for the free radical is the same as the carbocation, right.Because both are electron deficient. But I really can't understand the displacement of double bond in this case.

Comment: Can you draw a diagram to indicate the stabilisation?

Comment: I have added it to my answer,and I don't understand why that is not formed when acting upon allylic site (B)

Comment: 1) The triradical structures look *horrifying,* rather you would draw appropriate fish-hooks to move the double bond in one step. 2) Yes it is formed. Look closely. Look harder.

Comment: Please give some more hint or explanation, I'm trying but I don't seem to get anything

Comment: Actually the answer contains only those 3 as shown in the first image. Also, I want to know ,if this mechanism is correct, which one would be the major product? And**why would a double bond** split like that, because even before the free radical was on secondary carbon, and its the same even after bond displacement, what I really mean is **how would that double bond displacement help increase the free radical stability**?

Comment: What Jan is saying is, that one that you said was "not formed" *is* in fact one of the three products. Look closely. As for how the radical is stabilised - it's exactly the same way that a carbocation is stabilised. You can think of both the radical and the carbocation as being electron-deficient species.

Comment: Yes i see itin now ,thank you. But what about my other question, I.e., if my mechanism is correct then, I want to know what is the reason for shifting of the bond like I have shown, I don't know how it gets more stable. Please tell me a bit more in detail, I might be over looking few points ,which I don't seem to realise at this moment.

Comment: What are is the reason for splitting of the bond and forming bond like that? And which one would be the major product ?

Comment: SciFinder doesn’t find any reaction of 4,4-dimethylcyclohexene with NBS, for your reference(s). So the entire exercise is academic.

Comment: For the product mixture in allylic bromination, see here: https://youtu.be/BV_9wkYTeyA?si=kuTU6e4SGp09QhYv&t=290

Comment: For a textbook chapter that uses this example, see [worked example 10.1](https://openstax.org/books/organic-chemistry/pages/10-4-stability-of-the-allyl-radical-resonance-revisited).

Answer (score 1):

> [OP] I can't figure out the reason for the change in position of the double bond in the products.

This problem is a [worked example](https://openstax.org/books/organic-chemistry/pages/10-4-stability-of-the-allyl-radical-resonance-revisited) in McMurry.

The first step is abstraction of a hydrogen atom (radical), leading to an allylic radical. These show resonance:

[image]

As a consequence, a bromine atom (radical) can form a bond in two positions for the top, and in two position for the bottom resonance structure (for the bottom, there is symmetry, so you end up with the same molecule). All of the products are chiral, so products come in pairs of enantiomers, in a 50:50 ratio because everything else is achiral.

> [OP] Which one among these three products (disregarding stereochemistry) is the major product?

For other product mixtures, where the degree of substitution at the double bond differs between possible products, the one with the highest degree of substitution is favored (see e.g. [this video](https://youtu.be/BV_9wkYTeyA?si=kuTU6e4SGp09QhYv&t=290)). Here, there is no such difference. There might be a slight preference for abstracting the hydrogen further from the dimethyl group. There might also be a preference for not having the bromine end up right next to the dimethyl group (as in 3-bromo-4,4-dimethylcyclohexane).

In the absence of any of these preferences, the product formed from the symmetric allylic radical (3-bromo-5,5-dimethylcyclohexane) would be favored 2:1:1, just because of the statistics.